# Multi layer RNN cell and hidden state initialization?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Does each layer have its know initialization of hidden and cell state OR the last hidden and cell state from lower layer becomes the first hidden and cell state for the  upper layer?

Comment: I think it makes more sense if the final output of the states of the lower level is used to initialize the first input of upper level.  As all we are trying to do in RNN is to remember long-term dependencies. If we initialize each level with its own states and dependencies will be lost.

Comment: Interesting observation, but how do you want to calculate the hidden state in next time-step in lower layer without feeding data? Isn't it better to initialize the states in higher layers with zeros and expect to be fed from previous steps?

Comment: only the first hidden layer can have the initialization to cell and hidden state as zero. After unrolling the RNN for one hidden layer, the final value of cell and hidden state can go to the initialization of cell and hidden state for layer two.

Comment: @prateekagrawal that doesn't make sense to me unless you are using a bidirectional rnn and using forward last hidden/cell at layer n to be backwards init hidden/cell at layer n+1 and backwards last hidden/cell at layer n to be forward init hidden/cell at n+1. The higher layers are learning abstractions of lower layers. The order of information still matters, so jumping hidden information from the end of the sequence back to the beginning doesn't seem sensible.

Comment: I'd imagine just using a different hidden initialization at each layer would be fine. You could also learn different hidden state initializations at each layer. This would make sense to me as each layer captures different kinds of information so learning to initialise differently might help.